# React TypeScript project migrated to Vite - Slow Initial Load and Missed postMessage in Iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, iframe, vite

**Description:**

I recently migrated my React TypeScript project from Create React App (CRA) with Webpack to Vite. While the development experience has improved, I'm encountering an issue with the initial load time of the application, particularly when hosted within an iframe on another website.

The problem arises when the page is loading slowly, causing my application to miss a **`postMessage`** sent by the hosting website. I have set up an event listener using **`addEventListener('message', ...)`**, but due to the delayed initial load, the message is not captured.

**Additional Information:**

- I've ensured that the event listener for **`message`** is set up correctly.
- The issue seems to be related to the slower initial load time when hosted within an iframe.

**Question:**

Is there a recommended way to optimize the initial load time of a Vite project, especially when hosted within an iframe? Additionally, is there a strategy to ensure that **`postMessage`** events are not missed during the loading process?

**Project Configuration:**

- React
- TypeScript
- Vite

my vite.config.ts:

```
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import mkcert from 'vite-plugin-mkcert';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import fixReactVirtualized from 'esbuild-plugin-react-virtualized';
import envCompatible from 'vite-plugin-env-compatible';

const hostAppName = undefined;

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  return {
    envPrefix: 'REACT_APP_',
    base: '/',
    plugins: [
      react(),
      envCompatible(),
      tsconfigPaths(),
      svgr({}),
      mkcert(),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
      esbuildOptions: {
        plugins: [fixReactVirtualized],
      },
    },
    server: {
      host: hostAppName,
      port: 3000,
      open: true,
    },
    preview: {
      port: 8080,
    },
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
      modulePreload: false,
      target: 'esnext',
      minify: false,
      cssCodeSplit: false,
      sourcemap: true,
      rollupOptions: {
        onwarn(warning, defaultHandler) {
          if (warning.code === 'SOURCEMAP_ERROR') {
            return;
          }

          defaultHandler(warning);
        },
      },
    },
  };
});
```

**What I've tried:**

1. Migrated the project from Create React App (CRA) with Webpack to Vite.
2. Explored Vite configurations to optimize the initial load time.
3. Verified that the event listener for **`postMessage`** is correctly set up.
4. Implemented various configurations to address the issue, including using plugins like **`mkcert`**, **`svgr`**, and others.

project visualization:
[image]

I got this warning also when I build the project:

```
  (!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
```

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For the postMessage issue a common strategy is to make your embedder wait until the embeddee sends a first message confirming it's ready to process the incoming messages.

Comment: Do you know when is the parent page sending the message with `postMessaage`, i.e. does it wait for DOM to be loaded before sending it? Also have you verified that the message is received if you add a script with the message handler in the index.html head section? That is the first place where you are able to handle something.

Answer (score 1):

For your [Vite project](https://vitejs.dev/guide/), initial load time can be influenced by several factors, including but not limited to the size of your JavaScript bundles, the number of network requests made, and the efficiency of your code splitting.

Use [Vite's built-in visualizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-bundle-visualizer) to analyze your bundle size and identify large dependencies.

```js
import { visualizer } from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';

// Add to your plugins array in vite.config.ts
plugins: [
  react(),
  // Other plugins
  visualizer(),
],
```

Make sure you are leveraging [dynamic imports](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#dynamic-import) for lazy loading components and modules which are not immediately required.

```js
const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./LazyComponent'));
```

Other suggestions include:

- Some dependencies might not be optimized for [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules). Check if there are ES module versions of large dependencies or consider alternatives.
- Strategically use `<link rel="preload">` and `<link rel="prefetch">` for critical resources to load them earlier or in idle times.
- Make sure your server is configured to serve assets with compression such as gzip or Brotli.
  Use HTTP caching for static assets to reduce load times for repeat visits.

---

To address the issue of missing `postMessage` events due to slow loading, consider implementing a queue system for incoming messages. That means storing received messages in a queue if the application is not yet ready to process them, and then processing them once it is fully loaded.

But... as noted by [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78082517/react-typescript-project-migrated-to-vite-slow-initial-load-and-missed-postmes/78094727#comment137678829_78094727):

> The issue seems to be that they can't receive the messages at at all because they attach the event handler too late, so this won't work.

That would mean the problem is with the timing of attaching the event listener, which is critical in capturing messages sent to the window. If the event listener is attached too late, the messages sent by the hosting website when the iframe is initially loaded could be missed.

The event listener for the `postMessage` should be attached as early as possible in the lifecycle of your page. Ideally, this should be at the top level of your script, outside of any components, to make sure it is one of the first pieces of JavaScript to run.
And since you might not have your application logic ready when the first messages arrive, you might want to flag these messages or store them in a way that your application can check once it is initialized.

```js
// At the very start of your main entry file
let earlyMessages = [];

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (document.readyState === 'loading') { // If the document is still loading
    earlyMessages.push(event);
  } else {
    // Your app's message handling logic
    // Handle incoming message
    // If app is not ready, store it or mark the event for later processing
  }
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // Now that the app is initialized, process the early messages
  earlyMessages.forEach((earlyEvent) => {
    // Your app's message handling logic
  });

  // Clear the early messages as they have been processed
  earlyMessages = [];
});
```

If your application's initialization state is tracked, you can use it to determine whether to queue the messages or handle them immediately.

```js
let isAppInitialized = false;

window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (!isAppInitialized) {
    earlyMessages.push(event);
  } else {
    // Process the message immediately
  }
});

// Once your app is initialized
isAppInitialized = true;
earlyMessages.forEach((event) => {
  // Process the message
});
earlyMessages = []; // Clear the queue
```

---

> The issue is occurring in the `cloudRoles` component. How can I optimize the project?"
>
> Some chunks are larger than 500 kB after minification.

The visualization you have shared indicates that there are certain modules, particularly related to the `cloudRoles` component, that are contributing significantly to your bundle size. Combined with the warning about chunks larger than 500 KB, it is clear that code-splitting and optimizing certain parts of your application could improve the initial load time.

So try and refactor the `cloudRoles` component and related modules to use dynamic imports if you have not already. That makes sure the code for these components is loaded only when needed, rather than during the initial load.

```js
// Instead of a static import
// import CloudRoles from './components/cloudRoles/CloudRoles';

// Use dynamic import
const CloudRoles = React.lazy(() => import('./components/cloudRoles/CloudRoles'));
```

And adjust your `vite.config.ts` to manually define chunks for larger modules. That can help in controlling the size and composition of your JavaScript bundles.

```js
// vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  // ...other configurations
  build: {
    // ...other build options
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes('cloudRoles')) {
            return 'cloudRoles'; // All cloudRoles related modules will go into a separate chunk.
          }
          // Further chunk definitions
        },
      },
    },
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 600, // Adjust the size limit for chunk warnings
  },
});
```

Check if the dependencies used in the `cloudRoles` component are essential and if lighter alternatives are available. Sometimes, replacing a heavy library with a more lightweight one can lead to significant performance improvements.
Make sure the `cloudRoles` component does not import unused modules or code (for instance, using `npm install eslint eslint-plugin-unused-imports --save-dev`). That can also be achieved through tree-shaking (dead-code elimination) by making sure all your dependencies are ES modules compatible and by setting the `minify` option to `true` in your build configuration. (if you are using Webpack, you have [native support for Tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/)).

Libraries like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) can often contribute to large bundle sizes. If you are using such libraries, consider importing only the functions you need instead of the whole library.

```js
// Instead of importing the whole lodash library
// import _ from 'lodash';

// Import only the required function
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
```

Although you are using Vite, the principles from tools like the [Webpack Bundle Analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) still apply. You can use similar tools compatible with Vite to understand what is inside your bundles.

After making these changes, you should rebuild your project and revisit the visualization tool to make sure the size of the `cloudRoles` component and its related chunks have been reduced. If the component is still large, you may need to look into splitting it further or optimizing its internal logic and state management to reduce complexity and size.

---

> The issue is that I'm unable to add any code to the event listener or post message. The project is hosted in this `iframe`, but it's not our code. We only provide them the address of our project and receive the message.
> Before migrating to Vite, I used webpack, and it worked as expected; I was able to receive the message.
> Additionally, I implemented your suggestion regarding "manual chunks," but the issue persists.

Since you cannot modify the code of the hosting iframe, and that the issue has arisen after migrating from webpack to Vite, you should investigate how Vite's build process differs from webpack's, and how it might affect the timing of message reception.
Compare the output bundles of Vite and webpack. Vite might output the code in a way that changes the execution timing. See how scripts are loaded and executed, especially regarding `async` or `defer` attributes.

Look also into Vite's plugin or hook system to see if there is a way to make sure your message listener is set up in the earliest possible phase of the page's load. Vite's plugins might offer a hook that executes earlier than your current setup.

If your project is now missing certain [polyfills that webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin) automatically included, this could potentially affect script execution timing.
If you are running Vite in development mode, try building the project and running it in production mode. The behavior might differ between modes.

Double-check the `manualChunks` configuration to make sure there are no conflicts or issues causing chunks to become too large or not properly split. Make sure the loading strategy for chunks is not causing the `postMessage` handler to execute too late. You might need to fine-tune the `manualChunks` configuration or the placement of your script tags.

For the continued problem of missing messages, make sure the initialization of your `postMessage` listener is not being delayed by any other script or module. It should be one of the first things your entry file does.

Comment: Hey, I've incorporated your suggestions, edited my post, and added the visualization project export. The issue is occurring in the cloudRoles component. How can I optimize the project?

Comment: "To address the issue of missing postMessage events due to slow loading, consider implementing a queue system for incoming messages." The issue seems to be that they can't receive the messages at at all because they attach the event handler too late, so this won't work.

Comment: @Kaiido Good point. I have edited the answer and rewritten that section.

Comment: @VonC 
Thank you for your response. The issue is that I'm unable to add any code to the event listener or post message. The project is hosted in this iframe, but it's not our code. We only provide them the address of our project and receive the message. Before migrating to Vite, I used webpack, and it worked as expected; I was able to receive the message. Additionally, I implemented your suggestion regarding "manual chunks," but the issue persists.

Comment: @Manspof OK, I have edited the answer to leave some additional suggestions.

Comment: Hey, I haven't solved the problem yet. I'm continuing to investigate, but I acknowledge the answer and thank you for the effort and tips that could help solve the problem

Comment: @Manspof Thank you, don't forget to post an answer here when you will find one: you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Sure! I'll do it